# Unicodecsv suddenly write everything in one column

Tags: python, csv

[image]Last week, my Python script using **unicodecsv** was running fine, it wrote data to separate columns. Now, it just writes everything to one column.

This is the test Python code:

```
import unicodecsv as csv

file_tv = open('/Users/anhvangiang/Desktop/tv-shows.csv', 'wb')
writer_tv = csv.writer(file_tv, encoding='utf-8')

lst = [{'a':1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5}]

for i in lst:
    writer_tv.writerow([
          i['a'],
          i['b']
          ])
```

Previously, the csv file created would have 1, 2, 4, 5 each element in separate cells but now the first cell value is 1,2 and the second is 4,5. How can I fix this problem to make it work normally again?

Edit: I open the file using Microsoft Excel

Comment: Presumably you are on python 2.  Is this correct?

Comment: @KindStranger Yep that is correct

Comment: And how are you viewing the file?  Can you show the contents of the file if you open it in a text viewer such as Windows Notepad or similar?  If so please add to your question.

Comment: We need to see the raw contents of the file.  Can you right-click the file and open it with notepad instead of using Excel?  Please add the contents of the file to your question.

Comment: Are you using python within Windows or are you using a Linux environment to produce your file?

Comment: @KindStranger I use MacOS

Comment: Your script is working correctly. The problem lies with how you are opening it in Excel. If you attempt to insert it using Excel's `From Text` import utility and specify `utf8` format etc, it will end up displaying as you have it. Double clicking on the `tv-shows.csv` should open it in Excel correctly.

Comment: @MartinEvans I double clicked the file but it used to work in the past but it doesnt work now.